Gemini Status 429 no matter what
I'm unsure of why on earth my Google Gemini requests are returning status 429 resource exhausted. It definitely isn't because my resource is exhausted! This exact code worked a couple weeks ago...ugh.
Specs:

I have a paid account




Sending ~1M tokens
Via Python SDK using

def start_gemini_chat(api_key, system_message, user_message):
    
    genai.configure(api_key=api_key)

    safety_settings = [ 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}]

    generation_config = {
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_output_tokens": 8192
    }
    
    model = genai.GenerativeModel(
        model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
        generation_config=generation_config,
        system_instruction=system_message,
        safety_settings=safety_settings
    )

    chat_session = model.start_chat(history=[])

    response = chat_session.send_message(user_message)

    return response.text


The last time I received a 429 was during initial setting of Gemini.

I created a Google Workspace, and thought that was enough to send paid requests to Gemini.
But no. I had to Connect a GCP Billing Account. So I did that.


My two week Google Workspace trial has ended, so I activated my account




I even locked my Billing Account to my GCP Project. Didn't make a difference.




I recreated the API key and sent it along with the request. No difference...

I did notice, when I create a new API key, it says Free of charge...




But after the key is created, I refresh the browser now the key says Paid...







Does anyone have experience overcoming this status code with Gemini?

EDIT 1:
Added some retry logic for typical status 429 codes:
import google.generativeai as genai
from google.generativeai.types import RequestOptions
from google.api_core import retry

#--------------------------------------------------------

def submit_gemini_query(api_key, system_message, user_message):
    
    genai.configure(api_key=api_key)

    safety_settings = [ 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}, 
        {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}]

    generation_config = {
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_output_tokens": 8192
    }
    
    model = genai.GenerativeModel(
        model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
        generation_config=generation_config,
        system_instruction=system_message,
        safety_settings=safety_settings
    )

    chat_session = model.start_chat(history=[])

    response = chat_session.send_message(user_message,
                                         request_options=RequestOptions(
                                             retry=retry.Retry(
                                                 initial=10, 
                                                 multiplier=2, 
                                                 maximum=60, 
                                                 timeout=300
                                             )
                                         )
                                        )

    return response.text


With only this change, the code now consistently returns Status 503 Model Overloaded messages!!




Tested it this morning, same response




Very frustrating. Its like trying to troubleshoot something but the clues point you to non-issues.


Here is another forum post that this is being discussed in: https://discuss.ai.google.dev/t/why-always-getting-status-429-very-frustrating/35608/10

Tested again today, no code changes. Now the model returns a response...no reason found.
